# StreamReader to Tree View

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, streamreader

I have a text file (.txt) with the following structure:

- [ALPHA] [BRAVO] [CHARLIE]
- [BRAVO] [ALPHA] [CHARLIE] [DELTA] [BRAVO]
- [BRAVO] [ALPHA] [CHARLIE] [TANGO]

The hierarchy reads:

1. Alpha > BRAVO > CHARLIE
2. BRAVO > ALPHA > CHARLIE > DELTA > BRAVO
3. -------------------------------------> TANGO

This text file has potentially 100-200 lines. I would like to read in the lines using a StreamReader and then display these lines in a tree view.

So far I have successfully read in the file using a StreamReader and filtered the lines by [SECTION1] using .StartsWith.

I would like to evolve my application and output the contents of the StreamReader into some form of lists that can then be read by the tree view component.

My current code is as follows:

```
string currentFilter = cbTagFilter.Text;

            Console.WriteLine(currentFilter);

            IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(tbFileSelection.Text).Where(line => line.StartsWith(currentFilter));

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                lbContents.Items.Add(line);
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that represents your parent-to-child relationships and generate a list of those objects.  Then bind the list to the `TreeView` Control using `ItemsSource` property and use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to define the look and feel of your items in the `TreeView`.